# Find Deciles of Categorical Data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a couple different ways of finding deciles of numerical data.

```
modDF['RatingDecile'] = pd.cut(modDF['RatingScore'], 10, labels=range(1,11))
modDF['RatingDecile'] = pd.cut(modDF['RatingScore'], 10, labels=False)
```

Is there a way to do the same using categorical data?

I tried this idea:

```
modDF['RatingDecile'] = pd.cut(modDF['Rating'].map(lambda x : str(x)), 10, labels=False)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1043-58952d4c97bd>", line 1, in <module>
    modDF['RatingDecile'] = pd.cut(modDF['Rating'].map(lambda x : str(x)), 10, labels=False)

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 228, in cut
    mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in rng]

  File "C:\Users\rs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 228, in <listcomp>
    mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in rng]

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

The rating data looks like this:

```
AAA
AA+
A
BBB
BB+
B
```

Maybe it would be a count, or some such thing.  All I want to do is assign categorical data to bins 1-10.

I tied Label Encoding and One-Hot Encoding, and neither worked.

Comment: Which line of code does the error refer to? Please include the traceback.

Comment: I think you're a bit unclear about what you want to achieve. Do quantiles even make sense for categorical data? The whole definition of deciles is that they are an interval over which the continuous probability distribution integrates to 1/10. There is no continuous probability distribution for categorical data and hence no deciles.

Comment: The error you get comes from inside pandas. By asking it to compute deciles on your data, it will do some math with your data. Alas, it can't do math with a string like "AAA". So it thinks "AAA" + 0.0 means you want to concatenate some strings.

Comment: You have 6 levels of rating but want to cut them into 10 bins?

Comment: Yes, yes, it makes sense Lagerbaer.  Maybe I should just say AAA = 10, AA+ = 9, A = 8, etc. Is that the only option here?